# NodeJS & Javascript: Filter table with pagination

Tags: javascript, node.js, filter

I use [this code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) when I have table with little data and was very useful, but when I add pagination into table now it works only in page where I am. This is route with pagination that I need for filtering:

```
router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    const perPage = 10;
    const page = req.query.page || 1;

    ElectoralUnit.find({})
        .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
        .limit(perPage)
        .populate('town')
        .then(electoralUnits=>{

        ElectoralUnit.count().then(electoralUnitCount=>{
            Town.find({}).sort({name: 1}).then(towns=>{
                res.render('admin/electoralUnits/index', {
                    electoralUnits: electoralUnits,
                    towns: towns,
                    current: parseInt(page),
                    pages: Math.ceil(electoralUnitCount / perPage)
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Table:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="filterTowns()" placeholder="Filter: Ukucajte ime grada/opštine">
  <table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>IJ</th>
        <th>Datum unosa</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each electoralUnits}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{town.name}}</td>
          <td>{{name}}</td>
          <td>{{generateDate date 'DD. MMM. YYYY.'}}</td>
          <td><a href="/admin/electoralUnits/edit/{{id}}" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
          <td>
            <form action="/admin/electoralUnits/{{id}}?_method=DELETE" method="post">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- Pagination -->
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4">
      {{#paginate current=current pages=pages}}{{/paginate}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function filterTowns() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I Google for this solution and I find some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887759/filter-table-with-pagination) but no luck for my code.

How can I modify code from w3schools to filter through whole pages that pagination provides and not just in page that I'm current?

Comment: Please specify your question.

Comment: I edited because maybe I'm not being clear. I didn't want to copy code from w3schools because it will be to much code in here, I hope that you don't mind. Question: How can I modify code from w3schools to filter through whole pages that pagination provides and not just in page that I'm current?